# Python: Why import again in imported module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import, python-import

When I use the below commands in `main.py` file:

```
>>from random import randint
>>import sys
>>import <module name>
```

and I want to use `randint` in `<module name>`, then I need to add `from random import randint` again in `<module name>`, otherwise, `randint` is not known there: When I print `sys.modules`, it seems like `randint` was not imported. Why?

Comment: So you want to know why you have to import `random.randint` in `<module name>` if you want to use that function there even though you already imported it in `main.py`? I think every module needs to be a 'closed unit' working regardless of the context from which it is called. I see that you might think that this is not necessary, but that's just not how Python is designed.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Comment: thanks, understanding some.